# Why won't this bash script to drop caches work?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to make a bash script to clear my RAM caches.

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
#! /bin/bash

free -m
sync
sudo -s
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

But it doesn't fully work. The first three commands work perfectly, at the fourth command it exits.

Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo -s` creates a login shell session.  Then after you exit that it, you return to being a regular user.  Then it executes the 4th line, but you aren't root at that point so it fails.

You can't simply stick a sudo in front of the echo statement since that's a built-in command.

So try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

free -m
sync
sudo sh -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

---

> From *man sudo*:
>
> ```
> -s [command]
>      The -s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL 
> environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in passwd(5).
> If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution. 
> Otherwise, an interactive shell is executed.
> ```

Comment: If X is running, I believe it needs to be stopped `sudo /etc/init.d/xdm stop`.

Comment: @Zuul, the script will certainly run inside an X session (I just did).  Whether it clears the cache or not I didn't check.

Comment: @Zuul, also that command stops X only if using xdm, which is not the default display manager.  The right command would be `sudo service lightdm stop`.

Comment: yes, something along those lines, was just an example because I remembered not getting the proper result with X running. But thanks for adding the comment. Will try to add an answer to this question concerning all the facts from my experience.

Comment: Thanks man, it's worked. but faceing another problem, i add an extra command after 3rd line. it was free -m to see the difference. But it stops in line three.

Comment: works fine for me.  The third line will prompt you for sudo password so make sure to enter that.

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo commands after you use the non su commands or move the sudo commands to another script. You can time them with (example to free memory)

```
echo "free -m" | at 7:00
```

I believe